# Limit questions

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm make quiz app on flutter and have local json with 
questions(around 200). How i can limit questions for 40?
because when i open app its show me all question

```
 json={results:[
   {question},
  ]}

 final jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(json);
    final result  = (jsonResponse['results'] as List).map((question) 
     => QuestionModel.fromJson(question));
    questions.value =
        result.map((question) => 
    Question.fromQuestionModel(question)).toList();

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use subList function after using .toList()**.
this can be done easily by using .subList() which basically returns a list from the start index to the end index parameters from your original List ,like this

```
final result = (jsonResponse['results'] as List).map((question) 
 => QuestionModel.fromJson(question));
questions.value =
    result.map((question) => 
Question.fromQuestionModel(question)).toList().sublist(0,39);
```

**Note**
if you want to save all the 200 Questions and get every 40 questions then you should use pagination ,in this case you'll not use the subList function here, you'll use it after returning the result with the list that should be attached with the ui part.

**Bonus Tip**
check out this flutter plugin [flutter page wise](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pagewise) which makes the pagination alot easier, it can very helpful in a lot of situations.